# How to create a function that checks if one row in a PySpark column of a dataframe matches another row in the same column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

How would you create a function that checks if one row in a PySpark column(s) of a dataframe matches another row in the same column(s) of another Pysark dataframe? I want to make a new column that shows validation if that value in the record exists in the other dataframe. The dataframes don't have identical columns, except for the column(s) to join on. I'm new to PySpark. I know you have to use a withColum to create a new column that validates 'True' or 'False' for the differences. The problem is, that I'm using the subtract function to get differences of values on dataframes that don't have identical columns. So far, I have this:

```
def DoesValueMatch(df1, df2, column_name):
     name=column_name
     df1=df1.select(name)
     df2=df2.select(name)
     df3=df1.subtract(df1)
     return df3.show()
```

Thank you in advance! Much help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following dataframes.

```
df1.show()
+-----+------+
| name|gender|
+-----+------+
| john|     M|
|  amy|     F|
|sally|     F|
|  sam|     M|
+-----+------+
```

```
df2.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
| john| 12|
|tommy|  3|
|sally|  8|
| mary|  4|
+-----+---+
```

You can do the following to create a column indicating if the "name" column in df1 exists in df2.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df3 = (df1.join(df2, how="left", on="name")
          .withColumn("name_in_df2", 
           functions.when(df2["age"].isNull(), False)
           .otherwise(True)))

df3.show()
+-----+------+----+-----------+
| name|gender| age|name_in_df2|
+-----+------+----+-----------+
| john|     M|  12|       true|
|  amy|     F|null|      false|
|sally|     F|   8|       true|
|  sam|     M|null|      false|
+-----+------+----+-----------+
```

Comment: This works, thanks!! If both dataframes are joined on more than one column, all I have to do is on='column1, column2' right?

Comment: Yes, something like the following.

df = df1.join(df2, (df1["name"] == df2["name"]) & (df1["age"] == df2["age"]))

Comment: ^ Thanks. I can see how that is  much more detailed to do than using subtract